# qbxml isToBeEmailed Not working

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am using quickbooks web connector and have it working to import invoices in.

The issue is that the "IsToBeEmailed" is not working.

IsToBePrinted does work, but when i try and set the IsToBeEmailed the connector fails with: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

I have confirmed that "added" that XML element in causes it to fail, without it there the invoice imports.

Using quickbooks 2015 (CA) R7P

I have tried coping directly from the examples

1) using "blank"

2) using 1 or 0

3) using true or false

*** FAILING REQUEST ***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InvoiceAddRq requestID="1">
                        <InvoiceAdd>
                                <CustomerRef>
                                        <FullName>TEST</FullName>
                                </CustomerRef>
                                <TxnDate>2015-09-30</TxnDate>
                                <PONumber></PONumber>
                                <Memo></Memo>
    <IsToBeEmailed>true</IsToBeEmailed>
                                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                        <ItemRef>
                                                <FullName>Service Contract:TEST</FullName>
                                        </ItemRef>
                                        <Desc><![CDATA[ TEST ]]> </Desc>
                                        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                                        <Rate>1.00</Rate>
                                </InvoiceLineAdd>
                        </InvoiceAdd>
                </InvoiceAddRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

** WORKING REQUEST ***

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="1">
                            <InvoiceAdd>
                                    <CustomerRef>
                                            <FullName>TEST</FullName>
                                    </CustomerRef>
                                    <TxnDate>2015-09-30</TxnDate>
                                    <PONumber></PONumber>
                                    <Memo></Memo>
                                    <InvoiceLineAdd>
                                            <ItemRef>
                                                    <FullName>Service Contract:TEST</FullName>
                                            </ItemRef>
                                            <Desc><![CDATA[ TEST ]]> </Desc>
                                            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                                            <Rate>1.00</Rate>
                                    </InvoiceLineAdd>
                            </InvoiceAdd>
                    </InvoiceAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is that this field was introduced in version 6

so:

qbxml version="2.0"

should be

qbxml version="8.0"